# How do I serialize a parameter incoming from my controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

So I am sending a list of objects from my ASP.NET MVC controller back to my ajax success response:

```
...
success: function (data) {
                var predefinedData = data.serialize();
...
```

When I debug from browser, I see that the data parameter is reading as an array, which is ok, but the following error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.serialize is not a function

I've read that I have to convert the "vanilla" parameter into jQuery so I did the following:

```
var makeJqueryArray = $.makeArray(data) //this passes ok
var predefinedData = $.param(makeJqueryArray).serialize(); //but then this reports the same error as before
```

Upon further inspection I see that `$.makeArray(data)` literally doesn't do anything since it stays exactly the same as before, an array with n number of elements.

Doing `JSON.stringify(data);` works however, but it is out of the question since that gives me a completely different format than what I need here.

So does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

So here is the data I am receiving (as seen from the browser debugger watch):

```
data: Array[3]
0:Object
_int:false
avg:false
max:false
min:false
sensorID:5
sum:false
val:true
__proto__: Object
1:Object
2:Object
length:3
__proto__:Array[0]
```

And here is how i want to format it (the values don't match because I'm using different samples, but you get the point):

```
"SensorID=1&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false&SensorID=2&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false&SensorID=3&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false&SensorID=4&val=true&val=false&min=true&min=false&avg=true&avg=false&max=true&max=false&sum=true&sum=false&_int=true&_int=false&SensorID=5&val=true&val=false&min=true&min=false&avg=true&avg=false&max=true&max=false&sum=true&sum=false&_int=true&_int=false&SensorID=6&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false&SensorID=7&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false&SensorID=9&val=false&min=false&avg=false&max=false&sum=false&_int=false"
```

Comment: Don't you want to *de*serialize the incoming data from the .NET controller ? What does the serialized data looks like, and what should it look like once deserialized ?

Comment: @Protectator I'm not serializing it on the controller so it is already coming in deserialized in a form of an array with n elements

Comment: Can you post a piece of what the data you receive looks like, and what do you want to make out of it, please ? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Protectator Ok, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array and you want to make a request where the parameters are the key-value pairs of it, you can use simply `$.param(yourArray);`.
It will return a string ready to be used in your URL.

For example (taken from [the jQuery.param page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)) :

```
var params = { width:1680, height:1050 };
var str = jQuery.param( params ); // str = "width=1680&height=1050"
```

This should the same in your case. So, try this :

```
var makeJqueryArray = $.makeArray(data) //this passes ok
var finalString = $.param(makeJqueryArray); // Should contain the string you want
```

Comment: this is what I get (as seen from the browser debugger):

`finalString = "undefined=&undefined=&undefined=", makeJqerryArray = [Object, Object, Object]`

Any clue as to why?

here is my entire success function:

`success: function (data) {
var makeJqerryArray = $.makeArray(data);
var finalString = $.param(makeJqerryArray);
...`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: From what http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param says, the method also serializes objects recursively from version 1.4. This could solve your problem here : I'd try to update it to version 1.4 at least if I were you.